# Selenium Scraping: Clicking on the Next Button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrape

I am trying to scrape Federal reserve's press releases on `https://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/pressreleases.htm`, and to scrape documents from previous years, I need to move onto the next page by clicking on **Next** button at the bottom of the page.

I have tried a few things, but all of them return a `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:` error, and I can't figure out the issue:

```
#Attempt 1
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pagination-next ng-scope').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination-next ng-scope"))).click()

#Attempt 2
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='article']/ul[2]/li[7]/a").click()

#Attempt 3
    element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"//*[@id='article']/ul[2]/li[7]/a")))
    element.click()
```

Could anyone help me with where I am going wrong? For ease, the HTML for the **Next** button is:

```
<li ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-next ng-scope"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" ng-disabled="noNext()||ngDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle="" class="ng-binding">Next</a></li>
     <a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" ng-disabled="noNext()||ngDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle="" class="ng-binding">Next</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this code perhaps:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='article']/ul[2]/li[7]/a"))
    ).click()`

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as ***Next*** is an *`<a>`* tag and is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element.

```
<a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" ng-disabled="noNext()||ngDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle="" class="ng-binding">Next</a>
```

---

### Solution

To click element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Next"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.pagination-next.ng-scope a.ng-binding"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Next']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It works, thanks! Two follow-up questions: how do I click on "Submit" after filtering by Monetary Policy? I modified your solutions above and tried `(By.LINK_TEXT, "Submit")` and `(By.XPATH ,"//*[@id='content']/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[5]/a")` but both of these don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I am also looking for specifying the dates (on the same page). Particularly, I want to restrict observations from 01/01/2010 to 12/31/2021. Sorry, I am new to Selenium, and it is a bit confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @AYA Sounds like e new requirement all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: I posted it here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72071384/selenium-web-scraping-implementing-filters`